# How to write a locator to click the img using Selenium Webdriver and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to click the image with an anchor tag using Selenium Webdriver Java.

```html
<a title="Complete Step" class="tableIcon"           href="javascript:__doPostBack('__Page','COMPLETEJS_2309234_2_2_0')">
 <img title="Complete Step" style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px" src="/BTC/images/complete-job-step.png">
</a>
```

Comment: From this information there is a very large number of possible answers. Can you narrow down your problem. Have a read through [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below Xpath.It should work.

```
"//a[@class='tableIcon']/img"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple xpath:

```
a.tableIcon img
```

if you have multiple links and "2309234_2_2_0" is the unique identifier, then user the below.

```
a[href$="COMPLETEJS_2309234_2_2_0')"] img
```

Comment: Hi @supputuri..that is where am facing the issue "a[href$="COMPLETEJS_2309234_2_2_0')"] img" here 2309234 is dynamic value it is changing everytime...is there anyother way for this

Comment: Do you have multiple links with 'COMPLETEJS'?

Comment: if you know the dynamic value in the 2309234 place then you can replace that with the new value? Can you get the dynamic value from the application (eg: if 2309234 is order number we can get that after the order). Please the snippet of the html code around that link, so that I might get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

As the element is a *dynamic element* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Java* Solution:

  - `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.tableIcon[title='Complete Step']>img[title='Complete Step'][src*='complete-job-step']"))).click();
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='tableIcon' and @title='Complete Step']/img[@title='Complete Step' and contains(@src, 'complete-job-step')]"))).click();
    ```